# Print3D volume changes based on position of object

Tags: add-on, 3d-printing, volumetrics

I am creating a house and measuring the volume of each of my objects for a project. I have created a ridge tile, although this is not relevant to my problem. Under the Print3D addon, the volume calculator changes value depending on the position of the object. Here it is 679960.0124 cm³

[image: First position]

But when I raise the object slightly higher, no other changes but to position in space, the volume rises to 711007.3566 cm³

[image: Second position]

What is the reasoning behind this? And how can I know which volume is correct for any of my objects? Admittedly I do not know half of what Blender can do, but this seems like a bug.

Comment: The object seems to be irregularly shaded. Does it have any modifiers in the stack or any shape altering deformations like armatures, shape keys, or modifiers?

Comment: Thank you for the question. It is a little irregular, yes. I elongated half a circle, then duplicated it, made that bigger and filled in the faces between. The odd part in front is the same process, shorter, bigger, and then matched the vertices along the one end and filled in again. No modifiers, armature, or shape keys.